# How to SUM value result from using IIF AND RIGHT expression in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have used this expression to limit the data from "Process, P 4 , 3.0 GHz"
to "P 4, 3.0 GHz" using express

`if(Right(Fields!TECHINFO1.Value, Len(Fields!TECHINFO1.Value) 
- InStr(Fields!TECHINFO1.Value,  " ")) = "P 4, 3.0 GHz", "1","0")`

I got the result **1** on condition true but I also want to SUM all the true values in the new column or same column or new textbox.
I have search a lot but unable to find any helpful topic.
any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: use proper format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want them to sum up in a new column as a running total? There's a formula for that:

```
=RunningValue(iif(Right(Fields!TECHINFO1.Value, Len(Fields!TECHINFO1.Value) - InStr(Fields!TECHINFO1.Value, " "))="P 4, 3.0 GHz", 1,0), Sum, "Details")
```

Note that I have removed the quotes around the `...1, 0)` at the end of your Iif statement - putting quotes around them sets them to the String datatype, but if you want to do Math with them they need to be Numeric.

[You can read up on RunningValue here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255229.aspx) - it's a very useful function for getting running totals, and can be set to "reset" every time you change RowGroup so it can count specific categories and so on.

Comment: Boom Boom ! that is worked like a charm. Thank you for helping it.

Comment: i want to count the different processor 
scenario : 
we have more than 100 workstations and i want to count only core i5 and core i7 processors please see below procceers speeds : 
processor, Core i5 3.2 GHz (multiple computers)
processor, Core i5 2.0 GHz  (multiple computers)
processor, Core i7 3.0 GHz (multiple computers)
processor, Core i7 2.4 GHz (multiple computers)

core i 7 and core i5 are divided into two categories i.e 2.4 GHz and 3.0 GHz . how it can be done by using RUNNINGVALUE or should i use the MID function to count only processor, core i5 or core i7.

Comment: Well you could do something similar to what you already have in separate columns. I.E. have one column for "i5 Processors" and have `=RunningValue(iif(Fields!TECHINFO1.Value.Contains("i5") 1,0),Sum, "Details")` and then another column with `=RunningValue(iif(Fields!TECHINFO1.Value.Contains("i7") 1,0),Sum, "Details")` to count the i7 Processors...is that what you mean?

Comment: Thank you so much.counting means the different processor,well i have done it with your suggestion by using this expression : =RunningValue(iif(Mid(Fields!TECHINFO1.Value,+1,instr(Fields!TECHINFO1.Value,",")+8)="Processor, Core i7", 1,0), Sum, "DataSet1")     ... :)